# Calcular data de aniversario no typescritp

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de freela para um trabalho da faculdade e estou com o problema para calcular data.

Tenho um campo de data (para seleção de data) e outro uma label bloqueada que irá trazer o resultado (idade )  final, ou seja, a partir da data selecionada o sistema deverá fazer um calculo com a data do sistema e me trazer a idade do usuario

caso esse usuario tenha mais de 18, o cadastro ocorrera normalmente, se tiver abaixo de 18, ele ira alertar o uso proibido do sistema

Podem me ajudar

```
<!-- DATA AQUI -->
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
    <msp-input-date id="data-nascimento" label="Data de nascimento" tooltip="Ajustar"></msp-input-date>
</div>

<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
    <msp-input-text id="idade" label="idade aqui" tooltip="teste"></msp-input-text>
</div>
<!-- END DATA -->
```

Comment: da uma olhada nessa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd

Answer (score 0):

Como não conheço seu componente `msp-input-text` vou deixar um exemplo utilizando um `input`:

Template:

```html
<!-- Sempre que o usuário alterar a data ativamos a função setData -->
<!-- Neste exemplo espera-se que o input seja no seguinte formato yyyy-MM-dd -->
<input type="text" (change)="setData($event.target.value)" />
<span *ngIf="maior18">
  Tem mais de 18 anos
</span>
```

Componente:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  maior18 = false;

  setData(dataInput: string) {
    // Separamos a data para pegar o ano, mês e dia:
    const [ano, mes, dia] = dataInput
      .split('-')
      .map(a => parseInt(a, 10));
    const dataNascimento = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
    const dataAtual = new Date();

    // Calcula a diferença entre as datas em anos
    let diff =(dataAtual.getTime() - dataNascimento.getTime()) / 1000;
    diff /= (60 * 60 * 24);
    this.maior18 = Math.abs(Math.round(diff/365.25)) >= 18;
  }
}
```